# Доступ к MQTT-серверу из внешней сети для организации умного дома

Tags: php, c, arduino

Стоит задача сделать систему умный дом с использованием MQTT-протокола, перечитал много статей об этом и в большинстве описано как установить и настроить Mosquitto, но в пределах локальной сети, а меня интересует именно доступ из внешней сети. Вообще навыков использования mqtt у меня не много (если точнее то 0), поэтому я себе плохо представляю как это осуществить.

Сначала думал поставить mqtt-сервер на внешний хостинг и сделать некое подобие облака, на которое будут приходить данные и передаваться для отображения на сайт на том же хостинге, но я не нашел в интернете информации как установить mqtt на внешний хостинг. Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с решением подобного вопроса, то буду очень благодарен если подтолкнете меня в правильном направлении.

Comment: Если под внешним хостингом вы понимаете аренду виртуального сервера, то установка на него любого софта ничем не отличается от установки на физический комп у вас дома

Comment: В том и дело, что я имел в виду обычный хостинг, потому что цены на Дедик (сервер) слишком кусаются. Вообще как-то натыкался на Mosquitto-php но не понял подойдет ли он для моих целей, и можно ли его закинуть на хостинг.

Comment: Нет. протокол mqtt не может работать через http. так что http хостинг в любом случае не подойдет. Можете поставить сервер у себя дома и завести на него интернет с реальным ip (или реальный ip должен быть на роутере и порт mqtt на нем тогда пробросить на сервер). И сможете снаружи подключаться к нему

Comment: Я уже тоже подумал над таким способом, нужно только реальную ip подключить, но теперь надо определиться на что поставить сервер, потому что насколько я понимаю если ставить на ПК то тогда надо чтобы он постоянно был включен. А куда еще можно поставить сервер? Сама Arduino для этого подойдет?

Comment: Arduino мозгов явно не хватит. А вот залить на какой нибудь роутер OpenWRT и включить в него mqtt сервер очень даже реально. Ну или отдельный одноплатный компьютер на базе какого нибудь Raspberry

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду пробовать как-то воплотить это в жизнь

Comment: Использовать MQTT-брокер на внешнем хостинге - плохая затея, т.к. в случае недоступности интернета все перестанет работать. Вам нужно внутри локальной сети его поднимать, а наружу делать отдельный интерфейс.

Comment: Наверное вы правы, а как в таком случае выводить данные с брокера на сайт для отображение их там в виде графического интерфейса? Или возможно есть какие-то другие методы отображать данные с брокера в виде некоего интерфейса, а не в виде строк в консоли?

Answer (score 0):

Не смог ответить в комментарий, по этому пишу ответ =)

[How To Install and Secure the Mosquitto MQTT Messaging Broker on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-the-mosquitto-mqtt-messaging-broker-on-centos-7)

VPS (OpenVZ) сервер с CentOS 7 можно найти в пределах 10$ в год. Ищите на [lowendbox.com](https://lowendbox.com/). Например, [вот](https://lowendbox.com/blog/hiformance-2gb-openvz-for-10-00-yr-or-2gb-kvm-vps-for-5-mo/) (не реклама) =)